# regarding usage of arrow notation in perl

Tags: perl, reference

I've following two statements written in perl :

```
@m1 = ( [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ); # It is an array of references.
$mr = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]; # It is an anonymous array. $mr holds reference.
```

When I try to `print`:

```
print "$m1[0][1]\n"; # this statement outputs: 2; that is expected.

print "$mr->[0][1]\n"; #this statement outputs: 2; that is expected.

print "$mr[0][1]\n"; #this statement doesn't output anything.
```

I feel second and third print statements are same. However, I didn't any output with third print statement.

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with third print statement?

Comment: `use strict`. Always `use strict`.

Answer (score 6):

This is simple. `$mr` is a reference. So you use the [`Arrow Operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) to dereference.

Also, if you would use `use warnings; use strict;`, you would have received a somewhat obvious error message:

```
Global symbol "@mr" requires explicit package name
```

Answer (score 3):

`$mr` is a scalar variable whose value is a reference to a list. It is not a list, and it can't be used as if it was a list. The arrow is needed to access the list it refers to.

But hold on, `$m1[0]` is also not a list, but a reference to one. You may be wondering why you don't have to write an arrow between the indexes, like `$m1[0]->[1]`. There's [a special rule](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) that says you *can* omit the arrow when accessing list or hash elements in a list or hash of references, so you can write `$mr->[0][1]` instead of `$mr->[0]->[1]` and `$m1[0][1]` instead of `$m1[0]->[1]`.

Comment: References need to be accessed by ->, that's all there is to it. Think of it as the dereference operator * in C.

Answer (score 0):

`$mr` holds a reference (conceptually similar to the address of a variable in compiled languages). thus you have an extra level of indirection. replace `$mr`with `$$mr` and you'll be fine.

btw, you can easily check questions like these by browsing for [tutorials on perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html).

Answer (score 0):

You said:

```
print "$m1[0][1]\n"; # this statement outputs: 2; that is expected.

print "$mr[0][1]\n"; #this statement doesn't output anything.
```

Notice how you used the same syntax both times.

As you've established by this first line, this syntax accesses the array named: `@m1` and `@mr`. You have no variable named `@mr`, so you get undef for `$mr[0][1]`.

Maybe you don't realizes that scalar `$mr` and array `@mr` have no relation to each other.

Please use `use strict; use warnings;` to avoid these and many other errors.